# SpringBoot 2 health end point JSON format has changed

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

We have recently upgraded out Spring-Boot version to 2.1.2 in one of our applications.
I noticed a change in JSON format when I hit this URL:
http://localhost:xxxx/health.

The changed structure is:
{
Health: {
status: "UP"
}
}

Earlier it was:
{
status: "UP"
}

My question is;
1. Why has it been modified?
2. Is there any config to keep the structure as it was before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the release of Spring Boot 2, Actuator has been redesigned, and new exciting endpoints were added.

The `/actuator/health` endpoint is used to check the health or state of the running application. It’s usually exercised by monitoring software to alert us if the running instance goes down or gets unhealthy for other reasons. E.g. Connectivity issues with our DB, lack of disk space…

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator/health

{
status: "UP"
}
```

[Monitoring and Management over HTTP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-monitoring)

> If you are developing a web application, Spring Boot Actuator auto-configures all enabled endpoints to be exposed over HTTP. The default convention is to use the id of the endpoint with a prefix of /actuator as the URL path. **For example, health is exposed as /actuator/health.** TIP: Actuator is supported natively with Spring MVC, Spring WebFlux, and Jersey.

[Actuator Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-actuator)

> For security purposes, all actuators other than /health and /info are disabled by default. The management.endpoints.web.exposure.include property can be used to enable the actuators.
>
> If Spring Security is on the classpath and no other WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is present, all actuators other than /health and /info are secured by Spring Boot auto-configuration. If you define a custom WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, Spring Boot auto-configuration will back off and you will be in full control of actuator access rules.

[Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints)

> Actuator endpoints let you monitor and interact with your application. Spring Boot includes a number of built-in endpoints and lets you add your own. For example, the health endpoint provides basic application health information.
>
> Each individual endpoint can be enabled or disabled. This controls whether or not the endpoint is created and its bean exists in the application context. To be remotely accessible an endpoint also has to be exposed via JMX or HTTP. Most applications choose HTTP, where the ID of the endpoint along with a prefix of /actuator is mapped to a URL. **For example, by default, the health endpoint is mapped to /actuator/health.**

[Actuator JSON](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes#actuator-json)

> The JSON payloads returned from many endpoints have been improved with Spring Boot 2.0.
>
> Many endpoints now have JSON that more accurately reflects the underlying data. **For example, the /actuator/conditions endpoint (/autoconfig in Spring Boot 1.5) now has a top level contexts key to group results by ApplicationContext.**

[8. Health (health)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/actuator-api/html/#overview-endpoint-urls)

> To retrieve the health of the application, make a GET request to /actuator/health, as shown in the following curl-based example:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8080/actuator/health' -i -X GET
```

Useful Information : [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators#boot-1x-actuator)

Comment: According to the Spring documentation, the endpoint has been changed to /health. So it is no longer /actuator/health.
Also, your response does not answer my question. 
I asked, why is the JSON format different? Is there anyway/config to use the old JSO response?

Comment: check this https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/actuator-api/html/#overview-endpoint-urls

Comment: please read all provided links @Abhijit and also if you want this format `Earlier it was: { status: "UP" }` use `actuator/health`

Comment: how to format actuator output for better readability?